# Rogue Margin on Google Map element

Tags: html, css

Getting what appears to be rogue margin off of a google map element. The gallery should be on the right but this margin is stopping that. Can't seem to find what's producing this margin. Even the element inspector 'Metrics'? tool shows there is no margin, but the element highlighting on the screen shows a margin that pushes to the right edge of the page

[image]

My CSS for the element.

```
.gallery-map {
  height: 320px;
}
@media (min-width: 415px) {
  .gallery-map {
    height: 416px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 780px) {
  .gallery-map {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
  }
}
```

Explicitly set `margin` and `margin-right` to 0, tried to contain it in a wrapping div (that removed the rogue margin from the map element and put it on the new wrapping element) and several other things.

[A link to the branch I'm working on for this](https://github.com/MrJadaml/streetheart_rebuild/tree/responsive-d)

Comment: thats no margin, but a container fill color from inspector, because the map is absolutely positioned.
Small tip, always set the smallest media query last, because of inheritance.

Comment: You've fixed the width at `500px`, so the developer tool just shades the rest of the area of the element.  Note that the developer tool did not indicate a number for the margin.

Comment: @Mark it looks like it is relatively positioned, something that I'm guessing GM api is pushing in since the style is being set on the element itself, not something I'm setting.

Comment: @technophobia yea I saw that, but didn't understand why the highlighting was the same as the margin, or rather than why that gallery below didn't move up along side of it. with a `display-inline: block'

Comment: @Jadam, a `<div>` is allways consuming all off the space, it has relative positioning, the `<div>` inside, you set the CSS for it, 500px and its absolute positioned, therefor the gap colored as you think as margin-color

Comment: @Jadam When a block level element is given a width, the developer tool will shade the rest of the available area to indicate the containers block coverage. Note, this shouldn't happen for inline elements.

Comment: @technophobia @Mark ah ok, so a threw a couple of `display: inline-block`s on there. The gallery now comes along side (map disappears sometimes), but I feel like back on track. Thank you for the CSS and media query tips!

Comment: @Jadam - Feel free to summarize your solution in an answer and accepting it.  No shame in it, might help someone down the line.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was setting a couple of inline-blocks

```
.gallery-map {
    height: 320px;
  display: inline-block;

  @media (min-width: 415px) {
    height: 416px;
  }

  @media (min-width: 780px) {
    height: 500px;
    width: 64.5%;
  }
}
```

Also to get that gallery to come along side I needed to add the inline-block specifically to the media query

```
.gallery {
  height: 318px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  @media (min-width: 780px) {
    width: 35%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```